# What is the definition of "undetected" in Metal Gear Solid: Ground Zeroes?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes

I am really trying to complete the "Like a Boss" Xbox One challenge: *Clear all missions (NORMAL and HARD) within the time limit **without being spotted** and with 0 kills.*

[image: Like a Boss Achievement]

In order to achieve undetection do I need to be completely unseen? That means:

- No **white-arc warning on screen**,
- No **radio communication between guards** ("CP, this is Zulu X, I saw
  a suspicious figure, going in to check out."
- **Status alert remains Normal**,

I keep on restarting the mission not knowing whether I have or have not compromised the challenge.

Please specify what criteria I need to follow to be "undetected".

Comment: I saw a "no detection" speedrun, and I seem to remember him getting the white-arc warning several times and radio comms between guards.    I don't have the link on me, but a quick youtube search might turn up a quick run you can take a look at and draw conclusions from.

Comment: I don't know of a "Like a Boss" [Achievement](http://www.xboxachievements.com/game/metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes/achievements/) or [Trophy](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/metal-gear-solid-v-ground-zeroes-ps4/trophies/) for Ground Zeroes. Are you talking about the "Hero" one (`Cleared all missions (including Side Ops and Extra Ops) with a S-rank`) or is it about some DLC I don't know about?

Comment: @Nolonar I don't know how exclusive the achievement is on different platforms, but I know this is on Xbox One and it's a Featured Challenge actually. Where this challenge doesn't reward any points but it's for early adopters of the game since it has a time limit. Got 26 days left to finish this challenge or it's gone from the challenge list. Not a DLC at all, I've edited my question to include a picture of the challenge

Comment: I see. This seems like a Xbox One exclusive feature alright. I can't give you a definite answer, but I'm certain the white-arc and radio communications don't affect your progress. Not so sure about Reflex, though. However, I believe you can disregard stealth in Side Op 2, since that's a shooting mission and enemies already know you're there.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with Ground Zeroes

**Undetected** is when no one knows you are there. Let me explain:

> If an enemy sees you but it doesn't activate reflex mode (normally the
>   white-arc on the screen appears) you are still **undetected**!
>
> If the **Reflex Mode** is activated you must take him down within the
>   reflex or you will become detected. For your challenge specifically
>   you can't kill him since the challenge requires 0 kills. If you
>   succeeded in taking the enemy down you will still be **undetected**!
>
> While I was playing if they find bodies of other soldiers you will
>   become **detected**. I once forgot a body on the floor and didn't
>   think they would care but if you give them time, they will call CP for
>   support depending if the body is from a dead soldier or a knocked out
>   soldier.

I hope I was able to answer your question the way you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

from what I know of Metal Gear, undetected always ment no enemy contact, which means that supicious noises/person and the white arc does not count towards your detection stats. even if I had some supicion chatter on the radion in one of my stealth gameplay, it gave me the stealth playthrough note in my stats. since I do not play with reflex mode, I don't know if it will count as detected if a guard sees you and you silence him.